# Correct use of Spring @Transaction in service classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have a class that builds persistent objects from other persistent objects.  Simplifying the code a little, first are the methods that build locations objects:

```
@Transactional
private Location getLocation(PV1 pv1) {
    Ward wardObj = wardService.create(PV1Helper.getWard(pv1));  
    Location myLocation = new Location();
    myLocation.setWard(wardObj);

    return locationService.create(myLocation);
}

@Transactional
private Location getPriorLocation(PV1 pv1) {
    Ward wardObj = wardService.create(PV1Helper.getPriorWard(pv1));     
    Location myPriorLocation = new Location();
    myPriorLocation.setWard(wardObj);

    return locationService.create(myPriorLocation);
}
```

Now, we have the method (in a different class) that builds an admission object out of the location objects and persists it:

```
@Transactional
public Admission transfer(MSH msh, PV1 pv1, PV2 pv2) {
    String visitNumber = pv1.getVisitNumber().getIDNumber().getValue();
    Visit myVisit = visitService.findByVisitNumber(visitNumber);        
    Admission myAdmission = admissionService.findByVisit(myVisit);

    if (myAdmission != null) {
        myAdmission.setLocation(getLocation(msh, pv1));
        myAdmission.setPriorLocation(getPriorLocation(msh, pv1));
    }
    else {
        log.warn("Unable to transfer visit number: {}.", visitNumber);
    }

    return myAdmission;
}
```

What I have noticed is that sometimes the prior location object that is added to the Admission object is null or in fact has the form: foo.bar.Ward@7d26f3df  Otherwise the code works.  It occurred to me that when a transaction is closed that the object of the transaction - say priorLoaction is lost to the session and therefore when it is added to another object and persisted that the results may be somewhat indeterminate.  Is this correct?  Maybe I am not using @Transactional correctly at all?

I also have @Transactional on my service class methods:

```
@Transactional
public Ward create(Ward ward) {
    Ward created = ward;
    return unique(created);
}

@Transactional
private Ward unique(Ward ward) {
    Ward found = findByCode(ward.getCode());

    if (found == null) {
        return repository.save(ward);
    }
    return found;
}
```

Transaction manager

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()
            .getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Comment: Have you configured to use the Transaction Manager in your application context? Please show us that.

Comment: not sure how that happened!   It is there now

Comment: Do you have @EnableTransactionManagement annotation in that java config at top?

Comment: Yes - and the top of the class